# Subset a new dataframe that changes minuses the summed values of three dataframes from a fourth

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a four dataframes of the following structure:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06"), c(1002, 1200, 1111, 2211, 1112, 1621), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
names(df1) <- c('date', 'value', 'type')
df2 <- data.frame(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06"), c(401, 222, 967, 111, 982, 120), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
names(df2) <- c('date', 'value', 'type')
df3 <- data.frame(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06"), c(214, 151, 272, 295, 102, 211), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
names(df3) <- c('date', 'value', 'type')
df4 <- data.frame(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06"), c(107, 751, 614, 527, 125, 111), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
names(df4) <- c('date', 'value', 'type')
```

I'd like to create a subset of df1 (that keeps the date, but replaces the type with "Z") and for values minuses the summed values (per day) in df2, df3, and df4 from the daily value in df1. So the value for 2021-01-01 would be: 280.

The code I've tried is:

```
new_df <- df1 %>% df1&values-sum(df2$values, df3$values, df4$values)
```

However this sadly returns a "3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2" error and therefore can't move on to renaming the type for the new df.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Beware of **typos**: `df1&values` = `df1$values`, columns called `value` not `values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have many datasets with the object names having the same pattern (`df` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), load them into a `list` with `mget`, extract the 'value' column and use `-` with `Reduce`

```
new_df <- df1
new_df$value <- Reduce(`-`, lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")), "[[", "value"))
```

-output

```
> new_df
        date value type
1 2021-01-01   280    A
2 2021-01-02    76    B
3 2021-01-03  -742    C
4 2021-01-04  1278    D
5 2021-01-05   -97    E
6 2021-01-06  1179    F
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
new_df <- df1
new_df$type <- "Z"
new_df$value <- df1$value - df2$value - df3$value - df4$value
```

Output:

```r
        date value type
1 2021-01-01   280    Z
2 2021-01-02    76    Z
3 2021-01-03  -742    Z
4 2021-01-04  1278    Z
5 2021-01-05   -97    Z
6 2021-01-06  1179    Z
```